How can I calculate the input impedance of a negative resistance circuit?
I'm currently working on a project to design a circuit that makes negative resistance.
I designed the circuit myself, but it's hard to calculate the input impedance (Zin.)
The first picture is the circuit I designed.
The pictures below are the circuits and input impedance I referred to.
I'm most curious about Input impedance, but I'd like to know the flow of current in detail.




Why not use a simulator to give you what you want? Why have you omitted C3 in the 2nd circuit?

The same way that you would investigate a positive input resistance. Apply a current to that node, and record the voltage.

I think you should begin in a more general way and look at this block diagram: -

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
What you can then say is this: -
$$\dfrac{V_{IN}-V_{OUT}}{I_{IN}} = \dfrac{1}{sC}$$
Because \$V_{OUT} = G\cdot V_{IN}\$ it follows that
$$Z_{IN}\hspace{1cm} =\hspace{1cm} \dfrac{V_{IN}}{I_{IN}}\hspace{1cm} =\hspace{1cm} \dfrac{1}{sC\cdot (1 - G)}$$
That establishes the general case. If you wanted to you can add the input impedance of the amp as a component in parallel. Then you can use a modified version of \$\color{blue}{G}\$ that reflects the spectral gain across the frequencies of interest. You can also add the output impedance of the amplifier block if you want more sophistication.
I'd go this way (if I didn't have a simulator) rather than approach it in a top-heavy math way.

Thanks!! l will try again!!
